# display URL from mysql database in iframe PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, iframe

I need to display the URL for an iframe in a php file from mysql database.

the URL's get stored in mysql database in a table called videourl and a column called videourl.

i can get the URL from the mysql database and echo it on a php page but i cannot use it as n iframe scr !

here is what I have done so far:

```
<?php

echo  "<iframe src=\"{$videourl}\" style=\"background: #fff;\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"450\" scrolling=\"auto\" width=\"100%\"></iframe>";  


?>
```

but this doesn't work for some reason. and by it doesn't work I mean it doesn't show anything on the PHP page!

what is the best way of doing this ?

Thanks

**EDIT: This is my News code and still doesn't work:**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","db_username","password","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM videourl");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<td>" . $row['videourl'] . "</td>";
  }

  echo "<iframe src=\" . $videourl . \" style=\"background: #fff;\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"450\" scrolling=\"auto\" width=\"100%\"></iframe>";

?>
```

**Final EDIT:**

okay I've done it.

here is how you should do it if anyone is interested:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $id = $row["id"];
  $videourl = $row["videourl"];
  $date_added = $row["date_added"];
  }
echo  "<iframe src=\"{$videourl}\" style=\"background: #fff;\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"100%\" scrolling=\"auto\" width=\"100%\"></iframe>";
```

Comment: what is the actual generated php?

Comment: your not setting $videourl1 and the "." concatenation only works if you end the string. Your original reference {$videourl1} was correct but $videourl1 is not set

Comment: sorry i'm not sure what you mean by i am not setting $videourl! can you please explain it ?

Comment: @zgr024, there is not such a thing as $videourl1 in my code though!

Comment: None of the answers could help you because the question you asked wasn't relevant to solving the problem...

Comment: I meant `$videourl` not `$videourl1`

Answer (score 1):

What you did wrong is that you forgot to set the value of `$videourl`.

You fetched a rsult row in `$row`. After that you have to assign `$row["videourl"]` to `$videourl`, otherwise `$videourl` will be null and your `iframe src` will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

What's up with the curly braces? Try this instead.

```
echo  "<iframe src='$videourl' style='background: #fff;' frameborder='0' height='450' scrolling='auto' width='100'></iframe>";
```

Comment: Well, it would help if you actually set the value of the variable you were trying to use.